# Why is my "Align Rotation To Target" Option no longer showing?

Tags: snapping

[image]

Above is the snapping options menu open. For some reason, the option "Align Rotation To Target" is no longer showing. It should be between "Backface Culling" and "Project Individual Elements". I don't know why. It was just there a few hours ago when I closed blender. How do I get it back?

In latest blender version.

Comment: Looks like a bug. If you're able to pinpoint what action caused this, feel free to file a bug report via help > Report a Bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go into **edit mode** > **snapping options** (shown in the picture) and it was there. I selected it, then I went back to object mode and the option is showing again back in object mode.

Not sure why that happened, it's never happened to me before.